# Python + Selenium selection problems

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Thanks for the help with the previous, a bit longer problem @QHarr and @DebanjanB

This one is uncomplicated and comes from me being a total beginner.

I need to scrape the image location from this snippet from [webauto.de](https://www.webauto.de/site/de/auto-detail/v-id/121078258-1/fahrzeug/FORD-Fiesta-Style-1,3l-44kW-5-Gang-!-Nur-an-Gewerbe/Export-!-/Gebrauchtwagen/Limousine/silber/Benzin/44-KW-60-PS/Wesseling) + a click on the gallery

```
<li class="slide" style="">
    <img class="image" src="https://www.webauto.de/img/vc/de/0/1/2/19482/pan/1735h_1" style="max-width: 640px; max-height: 480px; width: 100%; height: auto; left: 50%; top: 50%; margin-left: -320px; margin-top: -240px;" alt=""></li>
```

And either

```
find_elements_by_css_selector('.slide > img')
find_elements_by_css_selector('li > img')
find_elements_by_xpath("//li[@class='slide']/img]"
```

leaves me with a blank list instead of a list of addressess.

The second thing is I need to select a subgroup from a JS dropdown on [hasznaltauto.hu](https://www.hasznaltauto.hu/)

```
<select id="hirdetesszemelyautosearch-modell_id" class="form-control hidegroups" name="HirdetesSzemelyautoSearch[modell_id]" data-live-search="false" data-header="Modell" data-krajee-depdrop="depdrop_fdcef640" disabled="disabled">
    <optgroup label="FIESTA">
        <option value="540" class="opt">FIESTA (1001)</option></optgroup>
```

And I used a logical continuation of what was provided to me but but it throws 'tuple index out of range'

```
find_element_by_xpath("//select[@id='hirdetesszemelyautosearch-modell_id']/optgroup[@label='{}']/option[contains(text(), '{}')]".format('FIESTA')).click()
```

Comment: find_elements uses the implicit wait time you have specify yourself. Have you tried using find_element_by_css_selector instead of elements? Alternatively, have you tried setting the implicit wait time to say 3 seconds?

Also I would suggest using the css-selector ".slide .image", but that is up to you

Comment: Do not ask two questions in single ticket. These issues are not related

Comment: lol ticket... that is how it feels sometimes

Comment: @g_uint "two questions in single question" sounds confusing

Comment: Yes, I have tried put the script to sleep for 3 secs till it all loads and nothing, the element instead of elementS here is my mistake, I've had it the right way in the script when I used it, rewritten it on SO with a mistake.

Comment: @Andersson It seemed to me to be an overkill to write two separate questions for problems involving the same framework, similar mechanics and similar level of simplicity.

Comment: @DrDro , no. It's OK. Also *"selection problems"* is quite broad problem definition. You should separate questions and use meaningful titles for both

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for full size image you need extract it in iframe

```
iframe = WebDriverWait(driver, 15).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "sb-player")))
driver.switch_to.frame(iframe)
images = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.slide > img')
```

Comment: This is it, it would probably take me while to google it out. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a CSS selector to grab all the image links. I wasn't sure what you meant by address but have used class selector to grab address under gallery.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

d = webdriver.Chrome()
d.get("https://www.webauto.de/site/de/auto-detail/v-id/121078258-1/fahrzeug/FORD-Fiesta-Style-1,3l-44kW-5-Gang-!-Nur-an-Gewerbe/Export-!-/Gebrauchtwagen/Limousine/silber/Benzin/44-KW-60-PS/Wesseling")
elements = WebDriverWait(d,5).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "[src^='https://www.webauto.de/img/']")))
linkList = [element.get_attribute('src') for element in elements]
print(linkList)
print(d.find_element_by_css_selector('.contactdata').text)

#d.quit()
```

Comment: This works too, thanks. Although the solution from @ewwink is shorter and more intuitive.